# Is it possible to fix garbage disposal leaking due to corrosion at outlet?

Tags: garbage-disposal

I had to replace the drain pipe on my garbage disposal because of a hole in the pipe.  When attempting to replace it I am unable to get a good seal at the outlet because corrosion has damaged it.  Is there any tricks that can be used to improve the seal here to better prevent leakage?

This is what the corrosion looks like: [image: picture]

Comment: Why don't you clean that debris out of the outlet so that the underlying material can be seen?  As it is, there is no way to tell.

Comment: I'd say there's far less "corrosion" and just a large collection of "gunk". It looks like the hole has reduced in size because the rubber washer was squashed out of place and has "frozen" into that shape from all the gunk. If that truly is metal that's deformed like that, then odds are really good you'll have to replace the whole thing. I doubt you can get just the outlet part. However, if you search "replacement parts `<make> <model>`" of your disposal, you might just find it's available.

Comment: I agree with the above comments; clean it and see if it's damaged, and if it is, toss it.  That said, I've never had any luck getting a disposal in such a bad state to remain leak-free for more than a couple of months.  The connection to the tube isn't so amazing even when it's new.   To the point that I'd be very unmotivated to spend time cleaning that up and buying parts knowing it probably won't last.

Answer (score 2):

Most sink drain parts are made of polypropylene plastic. It turns out that there's not much that sticks to PP so an adhesive based seal is a big ask. A gasket or o-ring of some sort will be needed. Those require clean, smooth, and flat surfaces, so let's start there.

The gunk looks like it might be a combination of rust, mineral scale, and semi-dried food slime. Some combination of mechanical and chemical work might clean things up. Maybe manual scraping or sanding, or soaking with an acid like vinegar. A rotary tool ("Dremel") with a wire brush or sanding attachment might speed the work.

If you can get it clean then you've got to find a sealing element. A big fat o-ring might do the trick if the flange on the outlet pipe is wide enough, or maybe a replacement outlet pipe will include a new gasket. You could even try using RTV silicone -- but note that *silicone won't actually stick to the PP plastic*. It *might* work to apply the silicone to the disposer outlet port, assemble the parts loosely, wait for the silicone to cure, and then tighten the parts so that there's mechanical pressure holding the PP drain tube to the silicone.

To be clear -- based on its apparent condition, most people would replace that disposer. But if you're up for a challenge and the time-vs-money balance makes sense, maybe these ideas will be some help.

Comment: That last paragraph is the key.